# Do I need a visa to transit Seoul on my way back from Jeju to Manila?

Tags: visas, airport-transfer, south-korea, filipino-citizens, jeju

I will be travelling from Jeju island bound for Manila, my plane will land in Seoul Gimpo and will transfer to Incheon, Do i need to secure a visa to get to Incheon airport from Seoul Gimpo?

Comment: I am from the Philippines

Comment: What is your immigration status in Jeju Island? If you have a visa, what type and when does it expire?

Comment: i saw in a website that no visa is required for Jeju, is my research correct? "If you want to visit Jeju Island for short-term visits, such as sightseeing or passing, you can enter without a visa and you will be given a maximum stay of 30 days." https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10101#this

Answer (score 2):

Jeju to Gimpo is a domestic Korean route.  Therefore you would not go through international customs upon arrival.  Simply walk out of the airport and hop on the train to Incheon.

Comment: Jeju has special immigration rules, so while they physically *can* do this, the question is whether they're allowed to.